# How to Target Specific Element in Internet Explorer using Access VBA

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, automation

First off, please forgive me for any mistakes in posting - this is my first time posting (although I'm a frequent visitor!

I'm working on a program to improve productivity within my workgroup. I am attempting to link an Access database to an internal web application (Pega based) that is very complex. Unfortunately, my knowledge of coding is very basic, and I do not have the available funding or bandwidth to obtain formal assistance. While I would love to use add-ins, I cannot, since my company will not allow it (I've asked, begged, pleaded, etc).

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykkip.png) is what the page of the program looks like. I first need to click the Work Manager Tab (WMT) blocked in GREEN, then I need to click the Get Next button (NGN) blocked in RED.
Steps I think need to happen

1. Bind the correct IE window session
2. Click on WMT
3. Click on NGN

I have been able use Access to bind the correct window and tab of IE (thank you to the person who provided the basic code for this!) but have not yet been able to decipher how to target the correct element on the page. The naming structure is a bit too much for my knowledge.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAaKg.png) is a screenshot of the HTML for the WMT (it won't copy it, at least not legibly, even after cleanup). I would love to be able to use the ID for the specific element, however, it's dynamic, and changes with each interaction, which is why I've been trying to target the static pieces, highlighted in green.

I haven't done much work with the second piece, however, [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyCqT.png) is the screenshot for that, with the button highlighted in yellow, if anyone wants to help there, too.

Thank you!

**CODE FOR THE WINDOW BIND** (works all the time so far!)

```
Sub C360WindowFind()
marker = 0
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
IE_count = objShell.Windows.Count
For x = 0 To (IE_count - 1)
    On Error Resume Next
    my_url = objShell.Windows(x).document.Location
    my_title = objShell.Windows(x).document.Title

    If my_title Like "Coverage User" & "*" Then
        Set C360Window = objShell.Windows(x)
        marker = 1
        Exit For
    Else
    End If
Next

If marker = 0 Then
MsgBox ("C360 window is not found. Please ensure C360 is open in Internet Explorer and try again")
Else
    'DO THE OTHER THINGS
End If
End Sub
```

**CODE I'VE TRIED TO TARGET CORRECT TAB** (Add in place of "DO THE OTHER THINGS" in previous code set)

FIRST TRY (does some crazy stuff that ends up making the program log out)

```
FindWorkManager1()
Dim C360doc As HTMLDocument
Dim Element
Dim ULTabName As String
Dim LIElement As String
Dim WMT_HREF As String
ULTabName = "yui-nav tab-ul tab-ul-t tab-ul-t-ns subTabsList"
ULElement = "getElementsByClassName"
LIElement = "getElementbyID"
WMT_HREF = "getElementsByTagName"

Set C360doc = C360Window.document
With C360doc.all
If element = ULElement("ULTabName").LIElement("Work Manager").innerText.WMT_HREF("a")(0) Then
element.Click
Else
MsgBox ("Please ensure Work Manager is open, then try again")
End If
End With
End Sub
```

SECOND TRY: Gets to the lines with stars and quits (tried a couple variations of this with same results)

```
FindWorkManager2()
Dim C360doc As HTMLDocument
Set C360doc = C360Window.document
    TabTagCounter = 0
    TabItemCounter = 0
    With C360doc.all
        Set Header = C360doc.getElementsByClassName("yui-nav tab-ul tab-ul-t tab-ul-t-ns subTabsList")
'Find the correct TabTag within Header
        For Each TabTag In Header
            If TabTag.tagName Like "UL" Then
            TabTagCounter = 1
'If we've identified the correct TabTag, then look at the TabItem
'*************Not currently working beyond this point :(
        If TabTagCounter = 1 Then
            For Each TabItem In TabTag
                If TabItem.innerText Like "*Work Manager*" Then
                TabItemCounter = 1
                End If
        MsgBox ("try again")
        Next
            Else
            End If
End If
Next
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Which element do you want to target? Is the `<li>` with `title` value of **Work Manager**? Or the `<a>` with `id` value of **TABANCHOR**? Please elaborate the specific element you want to target or provide the link of the website if you can. Besides, are all the ids are dynamic?

Comment: To  Yu Zhou: 
(1) A very good point! I did not specify :) I believe the click actually occurs at the <a> with 'id' value of **TABANCHOR** although I'm not 100% positive, as it seems to be associated with the HREF. 
(2) I cannot use the 'id' value of **TABANCHOR** as this is a very not unique ID for the page. The only static portions of the code appear to be the ones that are green highlighted in the code, above. 
(3) I'm unable to provide the link to the website itself, as it is an internal site, only accessible by my company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try to click the `<a>` tag as it's a link navigating to `#Tab2`. If the class `yui-nav tab-ul tab-ul-t tab-ul-t-ns subTabsList` is the only one, you could locate `ul` with this class name first, then locate the `li` and `a` with tag name.

As the real link is not accessible, so I make a test page like below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="tStrCntr">
        <ul class="yui-nav tab-ul tab-ul-t tab-ul-t-ns subTabsList">
            <li tabindex="-1"title="Work Manager"></li>
            <li tabindex="0" title="Home" id="Tab2">
                <a tabindex="-1" id="TABANCHOR" href="https://www.google.com">
                    <span style="display: inline-block">
                        <label>Work Manager</label>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the VB code to click **Work Manager** in the test page is like below, you could have a test:

**Updated version:**

```
Sub LOADIE()
    Dim link As Object
    Set ieA = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ieA.Visible = True
    ieA.navigate "http://the test web page"
    Do Until ieA.readyState = 4
       DoEvents
    Loop

    Set doc = ieA.Document
    Set ElementCol = doc.getElementsByClassName("yui-nav tab-ul tab-ul-t tab-ul-t-ns subTabsList")(0).getElementsByTagName("li")
    For Each link In ElementCol
    If link.getAttribute("title") = "Work Manager" Then
        link.getElementsByTagName("a").Item(0).Click
    End If
    Next link

End Sub
```

Comment: I do like the idea, and gave me ideas on how to implement the click. Unfortunately, it does not actually result in clicking on the Work Manager Tab. I cannot fathom why. I fear that it may be related to the dynamic nature, where the Work Manager Tab is not always the second item in the list. Is there a way to target the actual display text? Perhaps that would improve the reliability of the action?

Comment: @dualpoodle you could check my updated version of VBA code. It uses `getAttribute()` to get element with `title` of **Work Manager**.

Comment: Thank you again! When I step through the code now, it finds ElementCol (YAY!) and it finds links within ElementCol (YAY!) but doesn't find one with the attribute "work manager." What can I do to troubleshoot what is going on, and how to remedy it?

Comment: I retract my previous question - I was tinkering around with the code, and somehow, despite a different div having a different class ("yui-nav tsb-menu tab-ul tab-ul-t tab-ul-t-ns subTabsList") it was pulling that instead! So I changed the  `Set ElementCol` to (1) instead of (0) and IT WORKS!!!! I marked your answer as the solution. You are the BEST!